# Does Flash/Flex fully load a flv before starting to play it?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, streaming

If you have an flv of 20mb, does Flash fully load it before starting to play it? And if not, what's the difference then with streaming video?

Comment: At first I thought "That's what streaming is"..  You might wanna make it "...streaming the video thru FMS?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No your flash player will start playing as soon as it has buffered. This is called progressive download.

If you have a flash media server you can stream the flv. This will give you certain benefits, like:

- Having multiple versions of the video at different compression rates, which can be sent to the client based on their connection speed.
- The ability to skip forward in the video without needing to download the entire video.

Also another benefit to a streaming server it that it will allow you to stream live media.